# Split a large file into equal rows in R

Tags: r

Here is my sample data

```
library(dplyr)
Singer <- c("A","B","C","A","B","D")
Rank <- c(1,2,3,3,2,1)
data <- data_frame(Singer,Rank)
```

I would like to split the data into three separate csv files, and each of them should have two rows. I tried to use the split function, but it did not word out as I expected.

```
d <- split(data,rep(1:2,each=2))
```

Comment: Try `lapply( split(data, data$Rank), write_csv)` , although I admit to not knowing for sure which of the tidyverse packages has the `write_csv` function.

Comment: Which sets of two rows do you want split out?  Is it based on the information in the dataset?

Comment: I just want to split them from the top to bottom with equal rows.

Comment: `write_csv` is  in `readr` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group first, then use `do` to apply the writing function to each pair of rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

data %>% 
  group_by(g = ceiling(row_number() / 2)) %>% 
  do(write_csv(., paste0(.$g[1], '.csv')))
```